# is it possible to make different keys have independent watermark

Tags: apache-flink

I am using Flink 1.12 and I have a keyed stream, in my code it looks that both `A` and `B` share the same watermark? and therefore `B` is determined as late because A's coming has upgraded the watermark to be `2020-08-30 10:50:11`?

The output is `A(2020-08-30 10:50:08, 2020-08-30 10:50:16):2020-08-30 10:50:15`,there is no output for `B`

I would ask whether it is possible to make different keys have independent watermark? A's watermark and B'watermark change independently

The application code is:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.function.WindowFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{StreamExecutionEnvironment, _}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.watermark.Watermark
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.TumblingEventTimeWindows
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector


object DemoDiscardLateEvent4_KeyStream {
  def to_milli(str: String) =
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(str).getTime

  def to_char(milli: Long) = {
    val date = if (milli <= 0) new Date(0) else new Date(milli)
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setParallelism(1)
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
    val data = Seq(
      ("A", "2020-08-30 10:50:15"),
      ("B", "2020-08-30 10:50:07")
    )
    env.fromCollection(data).setParallelism(1).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks[(String, String)]() {
      var maxSeen = Long.MinValue

      override def checkAndGetNextWatermark(lastElement: (String, String), extractedTimestamp: Long): Watermark = {
        val eventTime = to_milli(lastElement._2)
        if (eventTime > maxSeen) {
          maxSeen = eventTime
        }
        //Allow 4 seconds late
        new Watermark(maxSeen - 4000)
      }
      override def extractTimestamp(element: (String, String), previousElementTimestamp: Long): Long = to_milli(element._2)
    }).keyBy(_._1).window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.of(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS))).apply(new WindowFunction[(String, String), String, String, TimeWindow] {
      override def apply(key: String, window: TimeWindow, input: Iterable[(String, String)], out: Collector[String]): Unit = {
        val start = to_char(window.getStart)
        val end = to_char(window.getEnd)
        val sb = new StringBuilder

        //the start and end of the window
        sb.append(s"$key($start, $end):")

        //The content of the window
        input.foreach {
          e => sb.append(e._2 + ",")
        }
        out.collect(sb.toString().substring(0, sb.length - 1))
      }
    }).print()

    env.execute()

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it would sometimes be helpful if Flink offered per-key watermarking, it does not.

Each parallel instance of your `WatermarkStrategy` (or in this case, of your `AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks`) is generating watermarks independently, based on the timestamps of the events it observes (regardless of their keys).

One way to work around the lack of this feature is to not use watermarks at all. For example, if you would be using per-key watermarks to trigger keyed event-time windows, you can instead implement your own windows using a `KeyedProcessFunction`, and instead of using watermarks to trigger event time timers, keep track of the largest timestamp seen so far for each key, and whenever updating that value, determine if you now want to close one or more windows for that key.

See [one of the Flink training lessons](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/event_driven.html#example) for an example of how to implement keyed tumbling windows with a `KeyedProcessFunction`. This example depends on watermarks but should help you get started.

Comment: Thanks @david-anderson for the helpful answer!